# how to connect flutter app to a local database and retrieve data to make a dynamic view?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am making an app for an existing website, I have a login page which has different users like admin, faculty, etc. How can I create a dynamic view which will work for every user?
sample programs will be helpful.

Comment: You need to create the separate Widget as per the login type of the user. No one will give you sample code. Try to create some sample and post it here if you are having any trouble. Learn routes so that you can navigate between page as per the user type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start here - SQFLite - https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite Follow the guide to setup

For an example of a login page a quick search on StackOverflow - [Simple Flutter sqflite login->write to db->navigate->retrieve from db flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55088501/simple-flutter-sqflite-login-write-to-db-navigate-retrieve-from-db-flow)

Comment: what to do for making a dynamic page for different user login, e.g- admin gets to see all tabs, faculty & students only sees few.  Do I have to make different views for every user? or I can change the view dynamically according to login and database fields?

Comment: Creating different views for every user case doesn't sound efficient, it will only increase the amount time coding, increase app size and make it harder to maintain. It would be a much better to have a single view and adjust what each user sees by user type.

Comment: I am a beginner in flutter so can you suggest how to implement that?

Comment: Quick Google: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/persistence/sqlite Follow the instructions. The Cookbook is a great resource everything you need is there.